# Is a jailbroken iPhone is necessary to extract the ipa of a pre-installed app like iMessage?

Tags: ida, ios, patch-reversing

My research notes: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y-2SZX4s1E1Mq9yWHZMMBzW3BJTfUuMl-YYXoZlY73w/edit?usp=sharing

From my research, I have come to the understanding that in order to extract the ipa file of an installed app in a non-jailbroken iphone, the available options are to either use apple configurator, imazing, or itunes. I have also studied the ipa extraction process for a jailbroken iphone, but given that my I am on an A14 chip iphone 12 pro max running ios 16.0.3, it is almost impossible to downgrade to ios 15 for a jailbreak, and a PPL bypass has not been discovered yet for A12+ ios 16+ iphones. Due to these unfortunate limitations, I am trying to set up a proper debugging environment in a non-jailbroken iphone if possible using this approach: https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2021/05/fuzzing-ios-code-on-macos-at-native.html

The question is whether a jailbroken iphone is necessary to extract the ipa file of a pre-installed app, such as imessage. The ultimate goal is to extract the compiled ios binary executable from the corresponding ipa->app bundle to run it as a macos process for debugging.